# Rotativa multiple PDF generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I am using rotativa to generate PDF.I want to generate multiple PDF based on the number of records in the list below code generate only one pdf.

```
public ActionResult PreviewPDF(string month,string year)
    {
        string basePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDFPath"];
        string fullPath = string.Empty;
        string message = CreatePath(basePath, month, year, out fullPath);
        if(message.Trim()=="")
        {
            List<FundMaster> lstFundMaster = commonRepo.GetFundMaster();
            foreach(FundMaster fund in lstFundMaster)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("PDFFactSheetData", "FactSheet", new { fundCode = fund.FundCode, filePath = fullPath });
            }
        }
        return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

above action will be called when i click on Preview PDF button where in based on the numbers of records in lstFundMaster List i want to generate a PDFs.Below action is responsible to generate the PDF

```
public ActionResult PDFFactSheetData(string fundCode="BAL",string filePath="")
    {
        FactSheet factSheetData = new FactSheet();
        factSheetData = factsheetRepo.GetFactSheetData(fundCode);
        FundInvestmentStyle investmentStyle = factSheetData.InvestmentStyle;           
        string pdfFileName = fundCode + ".pdf";
        string fullFilePath = Path.Combine(filePath, pdfFileName);
        return new ViewAsPdf(templateName, factSheetData) { FileName = pdfFileName, PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4, SaveOnServerPath = fullFilePath };

    }
```

Comment: The **return** statement `return RedirectToAction()` in your for loop, executes the first record and then immediately exits from the for loop. That's is the actual functionality of _return_ statement.